# .NetCore 3.0 Web API AzureAD authentication problem

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to set up a .Net Core 3.0 Web API and Angular application using AzureAD for authentication, all seems good except for an error I am getting when the Client tries to call the web API (see below).

I hit the angular application and successfully authenticate with AzureAD, I have followed all the instructions for exposing the API and granting permissions but no joy.  I wrote another test application with 2.2 and that worked fine.

Anyone having a similar issue?

Thanks, Mike

“AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID ‘f1be5414-b865-4fb4-9943-6dfc66c8fdcf’ named ‘MW Front End Auth Test’. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.\r\nTrace ID: 597358a2-5941-4c92-b458-a2ce6e276f00\r\nCorrelation ID: fd242c0f-60f7-4ddd-b951-ec49b93f831f\r\nTimestamp: 2019-11-10 16:36:55Z|consent_required”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is clear, consent required.

You can force **[user consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-user-consent#force-user-consent-through-a-url-request)** through a URL request, the url will look like:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<client id>&response_type=code&redirect_uri=<Your-Redirect-URI-Https-Encoded>&nonce=1234&resource=<your-resource-Https-encoded>&prompt=consent
```

If it needs **[admin consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-user-consent#grant-admin-consent-through-a-url-request)**, use `$prompt=admin_consent` instead.(need to use admin account to sign in)

Comment: I have a few questions... Which application am I providing consent to?  Front end or API application?  What is the resource url.

Comment: It seems that this is a duplicate of the MSDN Thread here : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3ca7d29e-0ff7-45e1-9577-2de1422e0efd/aadsts65001-error-trying-to-access-mt-web-api-from-angular-client?forum=WindowsAzureAD

Note that depending on the environment deployment, your consent scenario will differ accordingly. See the answer on MSDN, for more info, and let me know if there are anymore questions. Thanks!

Comment: @MikeWeston  Front end application id with api application id as the resource url.

Comment: @MikeWeston Do you have any other concerns regarding this?

Comment: Hi Tony, no sorted thanks for all your help apologies for late reply